# htaccess simulate rewritecond IF..ELSE against ip address

Tags: .htaccess

I have a **php_value auto_prepend_file** in my htaccess that I use with absolute path... This on my localhost, but when I upload on web server I need different absolute path...

```
#php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/web/server/auto_prepend.php"
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/local/server/auto_prepend.php"
```

Then I need something like

```
if ( ipaddress == serverip )
   php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/web/server/auto_prepend.php"
else
   php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/local/server/auto_prepend.php"
```

Comment: What version of apache are you using?

Comment: apache version is 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On apache 2.4 you can do something like the following :

```
<if "%{REMOTE_ADDR} ='yourip'">
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/file/"
</if>
<else "%{REMOTE_ADDR} !='yourip'">
#Your php_value directive
</else>
```

I have not tested this.

Comment: not working.... I have Internal Server Error

- **EDIT** Thanks, resolved changing ELSE to ELSEIF